# I get a PyBrain BackpropTrainer AssertionError on Windows 7, which requirement is missin?

Tags: python, neural-network, backpropagation, pybrain

I initialized `ds = SupervisedDataSet(12288,1)`
and add data `ds.appendLinked(im3.flatten(),10)` where im3 is an openCV picture.
and this is my trainer -> `trainer = BackpropTrainer(red, ds)`

When the running process reach BackpropTrainer, i get an AssertionError on backprop.py line 35 `self.setData(dataset)`.

It's a pybrain error on Windows, I developed it on Linux and it run without problem. I don't know what else to do, I tried to reinstall all but it still gets the same error. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you paste more of your code, which version of pybrain you have installed, and the full stacktrace of the assertion error?

Comment: It was the last version until that date. The funny thing is that it worked on Linux Ubuntu and not on Windows 7 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

The assert statement checks if a condition is true. In this case, if the inner dimension (indim) of your network is the same as your dataset, ds. Check if im3.flatten() is igual 12288

> > > assert ds.indim == network.indim   # 12288 != im3.flatten(), error!